# For-Next Loop and Arrays - VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, for-loop

I keep making the same mistake, and I have no idea what it is.  Every time I make a For-Loop dealing with arrays (usually, trying to read one array and write the values in a second array), it just takes the very last value from the first array and writes it in every single slot of the second array.

Here's a copy of the easiest/shortest one I'm working on.  It's supposed to read the values out of A1:A10 and write them to B1:K1.

```
Sub Problem1()
    Dim a(1 To 10) As Single
    Dim b(1, 10) As Single
    Dim i As Integer



    For i = 1 To 10
        a(i) = Range("A" + CStr(i)).Value
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 10
        b(1, i) = a(i)
    Next i

    Range("B1:K1") = b(1, 10)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Range("B1:K1") = b(1, 10)
```

this only copies a single array-element.

You could do the following:

```
Range("B1:K1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction _
    .Transpose(Range("A1:A10"))
```

To store the original values in an array would (using my approach) require it to be declared as a Variant, unfortunately:

```
Sub Problem1()
    Dim a As Variant

    a = Range("A1:A10")

    Range("B1:K1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(a)
End Sub
```

If you still want to make use of both arrays:

```
Sub Problem1()
    Dim a As Variant
    Dim b(1 To 10) As Single
    Dim i As Integer

    a = Range("A1:A10")
    For i = 1 To 10
        b(i) = a(i, 1)
    Next i
    Range("B1:K1") = b
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Problem1()
    Dim a(1 To 10) As Single
    Dim b(1, 10) As Single
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 10
        a(i) = Range("A" + CStr(i)).Value
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 10
        b(1, i) = a(i)
    Next i

    Range("B1:K1") = b()
End Sub
```

Comment: i am not that much perfect in vba. but the above is giving the output what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

For what you want, the better way that you could go about it would be:

```
Sub Problem1()

Dim a(1 To 10) As Single
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 10
    a(i) = Range("A" + CStr(i)).Value
Next i

Range("B1:K1") = a
End Sub
```

As for what's wrong with your current implementation, it's that you assigned one single to the entire range of a group of cells. better would be to loop through the contents of the array to output it individually into each cell. But vba handles this natively (outputting an array to a range of cells) as illustrated by my example above.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Problem1()
Dim i, j As Integer
j = 2

For i = 1 To 10
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, j).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i)
    j = j + 1
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You could eliminate `j` and just use `i + 1`. Also, note that you are declaring `i` as a `Variant` here. See this [Chip Pearson page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DeclaringVariables.aspx) and scroll down to "Pay Attention To Variables Declared With One Dim Statement."

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the steps as clear as possible, and read/write all values in one step to avoid having the output change the input (overlapping cells). The flow should be `[Read]->[Calc]->[Write]`.

```
Sub Problem1()
    Dim a() as Variant, b() as Variant, i as Integer

    'Get Values
    a = Range("A1").Resize(10,1).Value2

    'Transform the arrays in any way you need.
    'Make sure the intent is clear
    ReDim b(1 to 1, 1 to 10)
    For i=1 to 10
        b(1,i) = a(i,1)
    Next i

    'Set Values
    Range("B1").Resize(1,10).Value2 = b

End Sub
```